# Can't not config store using redux in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

i got that problem in my project "store.getState is not a function
TypeError: store.getState is not a function"

This is in **configStore.js**

```
import { combineReducers,createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux"

import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import TodoListReducer from "./reducers/TodoListReducer"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    TodoListReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware)

export default store
```

This is in **reducer.js**

```
import { GET_TASK_API } from "../constrains/TodoListConst"

const initialState = {
    taskList: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TASK_API:
            state.taskList = action.taskList
            return { ...state }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This is **index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

//set up redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/configStore';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    <React.StrictMode >
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

i think i use createStore and and it were too old support, i try to change to configureStore (redux toolkit), so that not fix so much. Maybe im not try so much. But i need help a little bit !!!

Comment: Can you show the full error stack? And, create a reproducible running https://codesandbox.io/ example